# Changing HTML Attribute w/ JS in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

The idea is to change the attribute of a specific DOM element, in which the attribute is "transform class" and the value is "selected".

I've tried in both JS:

```
  var d = document.getElementById("model-chart.span2.dc-chart svg g rect");
  d.setAttribute("transform class", "selected");
```

Along with jQuery

```
 $('#model-chart.span2.dc-chart svg g rect').attr("transform class", "selected");
```

The errors, however, are leading me to believe that you can't have multiple words in the first input for .attr or .setAttribute

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'transform class' is not a valid attribute name.`
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

Has anyone else ran into this or have any suggestions on how I can change the attribute class of a DOM element immediately after the page is done loading without using the .attr or setAttribute method?

Comment: Are you trying to set multiple attributes at once? And should the value of both of them be "selected"?

Comment: No, just the one attribute so when the page loads, a particular D3 chart is immediately active instead of having to select it.

I just provided two examples of me trying, specifically in jQuery and Javascript. I'm not sure if there's a D3 way of doing it-- I couldn't find anything in their API.

Comment: But how can `trasform class` be one attribute?  As far as i know spaces are not allowed in attribute names.

Comment: You can't have spaces in attribute names.